# Composer require output message Killed

Tags: symfony, composer-php, bundles

When I tried to require

`composer require nelmio/solarium-bundle`

command is end with message

> Killed.

Also when I tried to do

`composer require nelmio/solarium-bundle --profile`

Everything is fine but no class in Vendor folder. composer.json update it self but composer.lock is not updated.

I just want to try manually to add data for nelmio/solarium-bundle but cannot find data I need to import in composer.lock file.

Comment: Manually updating `composer.lock` sounds like a bad idea to me. It would be very easy to put it into an inconsistent state. If you revert both `composer.json` and `composer.lock` to the last known good state and then run `composer require nelmio/solarium-bundle` does it still crash? Are you running out of memory?

Comment: Check your PHP error log to see if an error is being thrown, and you can also run composer with `-vvv` to increase verbosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:

I using VM and I allow 1 Gb ram for nginx server. 
In some reason solarium bundle is need over 2Gb ram to install.

To check how much ram is used while composer install you can add

> --profile

at end of composer command, in this case it was

```
composer require nelmio/solarium-bundle --profile
```